# Contribution page profile not displaying at top of page, above billing section, despite configuration

Tags: civicontribute, profile, contribution-page

Newbie question. CiviCRM v 4.7.18. WordPress 4.7.3 running GeneratePress theme.

---

I have created a new contribution page and embedded it with shortcode in my Wordpress site (sorry, not public yet so no link). I'm using Paypal Express for payment processor.

In configuring the contribution page, I added a profile to appear at the TOP of the page. However, it displays BELOW the billing section. I tried moving the profile to the bottom position, and then to the top again. It always displays at the bottom, no matter which position I choose (only 1 profile chosen). I also tried selected a different profile, and that makes no difference. This is my first contribution page on this site.

Is there some other setting in CiviCRM that also controls the position that I need to change?  Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you put a profile in the top and bottom? Does it display one in each position?

Comment: Good question, Carl. I tried and it displayed both at bottom. I also tested with with hijack setting, cleared browser cache, and in different browser where not logged in.

Comment: To be clear, at this point, the Amounts and Email fields of the contribution part are above the profile (not what I want), but the big yellow Paypal button is below the profile (good). Is that normal?  I would swear the yellow Paypal button was above the profile earlier. I would prefer the profile to be above the Amounts and Email fields.

Comment: always worth seeing what happens on the Demo sites to give you something to compare to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the Profile above the amounts. I do not use Paypal so I do not know what you payment portions look like.  For me (using iATS with WordPress), my *Profile* placement options are 1. below the amounts (including the "is recurring option") but above the payment info/billing or 2. below the payment info but above the *Confirm Contribution* button.

Comment: Carl's answer helped me. I still think the yellow payment button moved during my tinkering, but not sure why/how.